# IOS InAppPurchase content download from my own server

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I am developing an application. In this application new user will get access to download three images from my own PHP server. After downloading 2 images he then needs to purchase subscription for (1-Year) via an in-app-purchase. Then user will be able to download all available images from the server.

After completion of 1 Year subscription the user will need to renew his subscription, otherwise all downloaded content should be deleted from his device.

How can I approach this requirement using InAppPurchase? Which type of InAppPurchase do I have to implement (Consumable, Non consumable or Subscriptions)?

Comment: Apple provide Auto-Renewable Subscriptions you need to check apple doc https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf

Comment: You describe a subscription, and ask "what payment model should I use from these options?" -- one of which is a subscription. It's not clear why you felt the need to ask a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you want the user to auto-renew, use an Auto-renewing Subscription.
- If you want the user to manually renew, use a non-renewing Subscription.

The use cases for both of these are covered pretty clearly in Apple's documentation: "Getting Started with In-App Purchases on iOS and OS X" ( https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf )

The user experience for each of these is different and you'll need to take that into consideration in addition to the coding complexity when you choose which path to take.

There is no one "right" answer, only the one that's right for your intent and audience.

Comment: Thanks Brad,my doubt is if user does't subscribe next year user had no rights to access that content. That's ok but according to my client requirement i need to delete that content from documents directory.  Is it fine according auto renewal subscription?

Comment: Everything I know about it says that the important part there is to make sure it's **clear to the subscriber what's going to happen**: the auto-renewal and the effects of canceling both. Communication/awareness is key. If you do that, then yes. I've specifically worked on a project (in the App Store today) where the product had free content and subscribed content; if the subscription lapses, the premium content goes away.

Note that you can also do this with consumables, but it gets much more difficult to manage; I don't recommend it.

Stay away from non-consumables for your described purpose.

Comment: Thank you very much Brad for sharing your valuable experience.